# Type of noun from the sentence

Tags: nouns, proper-nouns, collective-nouns, abstract-nouns

"Seeing the baby the mother rose in her."

Is the word 'mother' in the above sentence a:
(a) Common Noun
(b) Abstract Noun
(c) Proper Noun
(d) Collective Noun

Comment: (e) Do your own homework.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please [edit] your post providing the definitions you have found for each type of noun, and why you are confused as to which one would apply here. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance. Also, our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may be better-suited to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robikul,

Welcome to English stackexchange.

The word `'mother'` is a `common noun` but it becomes a `proper noun` and is `capitalized` when it is used as a name for the mother. This only happens in writing.

Examples:
“I want to ask my mother whether she is going with us.” `(common)`
“Do you want to go with us, Mother?” `(proper)`

Therfore, in your sentence, the word is used as a common noun.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have learned a beautiful grammar rule from you. Would you please provide me any website where I can learn all the best grammar rules for competitive exam? Your explanation is really impressed me very much.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to English language & usage!

It’s (a).

**Common nouns:**

Common nouns are ordinary things like: things, animals, people names, places and so on. They can be abstract (the ones you can’t touch) or concrete (the ones you can touch).

> Desk, dog, teacher, beach...

**Proper nouns:**

Proper nouns are the proper, specific names of people, days/months, things, animals, places etc...

> Mary, April, Italy...

**Abstract nouns:**

Abstract nouns are the ones we can’t feel with our senses, they are mostly feelings and ideas.

> happiness, anger, sadness...

**Collective nouns:**

Collective nouns are used to describe a group of people, animals, things...

> A **swarm** of bees; a **fleet** of ships...

Comment: Please accept my question if it helped you! :)